# need help on java grading program? i need to make a program that reads the percentage of a students total grade

Tags: java, percentage

I have a problem. I have this program that I'm supposed to create, it's supposed to read the grade for two quizzes that both add up to 25 percent of the students total grade, a midterm exam that is 25 percent of the students grade and a final exam that is 50 percent of total grade. When I run the program everything is ok except when I put 7 for first quiz grade , 8 for second quiz grade, 90 for midterm and 80 for final the total grade should be 81.25 percent but instead it displays .8125 and automatically gives the student an F. i don't know how to fix it....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentClass {
// calculate grade first then the if else statements for the letter grade
    public static Scanner grades = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static double quiz1, quiz2, midterm, finalExam, Grades, totalGrade, bothQuizzes, PfinalExam, PmidTerm;
    public static String studentname;
    public static int Score;


    public String getstudentname( )
    {
        return studentname;
    }
    public double getquiz1()
    {
        return quiz1;
    }

    public double getquiz2 ()
    {
        return quiz2;
    }

    public double midterm()
    {
        return midterm;
    }

    public double finalExam()
    {
        return finalExam;
    }

    public void setquiz1 (double quiz1)
    {
        this.quiz1 = quiz1;
    }

    public void setquiz2 (double quiz2)
    {
        this.quiz2 = quiz2;
    }

    public void setmidterm()
    {
        this.midterm = midterm;
    }

    public void setfinalExam()
    {
        this.finalExam = finalExam;
    }

    public void setGrades ()
    {

    }

    public String toString(){

        return this.quiz1 + " " + this.quiz2 + " " + this.midterm + " " + this.finalExam;

    }



    public static void  readInput(){

        System.out.println("Please enter the grade you got for the first quiz: ");
        quiz1 = grades.nextInt();

        while (quiz1 <0 || quiz1>10)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade between zero and ten: ");
            quiz1 = grades.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the grade you got for the second quiz: ");
        quiz2 = grades.nextInt();

        while (quiz2 <0 || quiz2>10)

        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade between zero and ten: ");
            quiz2 = grades.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the grade you got on your midterm: ");
        midterm = grades.nextInt();

        while (midterm <0 || midterm>100)

        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade between 0 and 100: ");
            midterm = grades.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the grade you got on your final exam: ");
        finalExam = grades.nextInt();

        while (finalExam < 0 || finalExam > 100)

        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade between 0 and 100: ");
            finalExam = grades.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static  void output()

    {

        System.out.println(" your score for the first quiz was " + quiz1 );

        System.out.println("your score for the second quiz was " + quiz2);

        System.out.println(" your score for the midterm was " + midterm );

        System.out.println("your score for the final exam was " + finalExam);
        bothQuizzes = ((quiz1 + quiz2)/20)*.25;
        PmidTerm = (midterm/100) *.25;
        PfinalExam = (finalExam/100) * .50;

        totalGrade = bothQuizzes + PmidTerm + PfinalExam;

        System.out.println("Your total grade for these grades is " + totalGrade);

        double letterGrade = totalGrade;
        if (letterGrade >= 90)

        {

            System.out.println("Your grade is an A");

            // grade = "A";

        }

        else if (letterGrade >= 80)

        {

            System.out.println("Your grade is a B");

        }

        else if (letterGrade >= 70)

        {

            System.out.println("Your grade is a C");

        }

        else if (letterGrade >= 60)

        {

            System.out.println("Your grade is a D");

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Your grade is an F");



        }

    }


    }
```

Comment: I think people read your title, see the first couple sentences and lack of capitalization, and down-vote your question thinking you are asking for code and didn't take the time to properly format your question. You may want to edit it.

Comment: yeah i was like why did i get like a million down votes? i didn't beg people for code like the millions of people on here , i just needed help.

Answer (score 3):

```
    bothQuizzes = ((quiz1 + quiz2)/20)*.25;
    PmidTerm = (midterm/100) *.25;
    PfinalExam = (finalExam/100) * .50;

    totalGrade = bothQuizzes + PmidTerm + PfinalExam;
```

Assuming you enter integer values from 0 to 100, this will give you:

bothQuizzes: a value between 0 and 2.5
PmidTerm: a value between  0 and .25
PfinalExam: a value between 0 and .50

You obviously have some mathematical problems here.

You should change the first line here to

```
 bothQuizzes = ((quiz1 + quiz2)/200) *.25
```

Looks like you dropped a 0 somewhere.  This will give you values between 0 and 0.25

This means totalGrade will be between 0 and 1.00.  You should multiply this by 100, so you have:

```
 totalgrade = 100*(bothQuizzes + PmidTerm + PfinalExam)
```

To display with a percentage:

```
 System.out.println("Your total grade for these grades is " + totalGrade + "%");
```

Comment: actually i fixed it, it correctly gives me 81.25% now , thanks guys! it's funny how one little mistakes ruins an entire program... lol

Comment: multiplying by 100 moved the decimal place two places to the right thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you get 0.8125 just multiply by 100 and append a '%' to get 81.25%.

```
String gradeStr = (totalGrade*100) + "%";
System.out.println(gradeStr);
```

To clarify, you aren't using `%` as in the modulo operator, but as a string.

Comment: can you elaborate more on that please? and thank you for the quick response, like where would i insert the percentage sign, i know the percentage sign gives you the remainder...